# instance variable in block when using define_method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to do a DSL, in which the user can pass a block and expect an instance variable `@arg` to be defined. This is a full example with a unit test failing:

```rb
# Implementation
class Filter
  def initialize
    @arg = 'foo'
  end

  def self.filters &block
    define_method :filter do |els|
      els.select &block
    end
  end
end

# Usage
class Foo < Filter
  filters {|el| el == @arg}
end

# Expected behavior
describe 'filters created with the DSL' do
  subject { Foo.new }
  it 'can use @arg in the filters block' do
    els = %w[notthearg  either  foo  other]
    expect(subject.filter els).to be_eql(['foo'])
  end
end
```

Using `pry` or putting `puts` statements inside the block, I can see that `@arg` is nil. But `Foo.new.instance_variable_get :@arg` correctly outputs `foo`, so it must be related to some scoping rules.

What do I need to change in the implementation to make the test pass and the DSL to work?

Comment: @Stefan The `@arg` of the class in which I'm calling `filter`. How could I tweak the implementation then so the `@arg` in the block gets evaluated in the scope of the instantiated class?

Comment: @Stefan: `filter` _is_ an instance method. `filters`, which sets up `filter`, is a class method. However, `filters` captures a block in a class context and passes it on to `filter`; OP wishes to have the block executed in the instance context. (Not saying it's possible or impossible just yet, my brain hurts.)

Comment: @Amadan Stefan nailed it in the last comment, that's my problem exactly. I need a class method for `filters` so I can create the DSL in the post (which is part of a bigger project), or at least I think I do. The end objective here is to tweak the implementation so the test passes for the example filter `Foo` that I have created.

Comment: @Amadan oh I see, I thought `filter` and `filters` were the same. I missed the `define_method` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instance_exec` to rescue!

```
class Filter
  def initialize
    @arg = 'foo'
  end

  def self.filters &block
    define_method :filter do |els|
      els.select { |e| self.instance_exec(e, &block) }
    end
  end
end

class Foo < Filter
  filters {|el| el == @arg }
end

Foo.new.filter(%w[notthearg  either  foo  other])
# => ["foo"]
```

Caution: Make sure this is *very* well documented, since any shenanigans involving `instance_exec` or its cousins are breaking programmer expectations left and right - by design, you're destroying the concept of "scope". I'm pretty sure OP knows this, but it is worth putting down on the proverbial paper.

Also, consider using accessors rather than plain instance variables - accessors are checked, and variables are not. i.e. `{ |el| el == urg }` will result in an error, but `{ |el| el == @urg }` will silently fail (and filter for `nil`).

Comment: You are right about the accessors, I'll do that. Thanks!